# Debugging of entity framework migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project that throws an exception on `Add-Migration` and on `Update-Database`, what would be the best way to debug this? I would like to attach the debugger so I can step through the Entity Framework 6 sourcecode, but how can I get a breakpoint or debugger in when I run these commands from the `Package Manager Console`?

Answer (score 1):

If you put:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

...somewhere in your code, it'll start up another instance of Visual Studio.

I use this when debugging the seed method.  I presume it works pretty much anywhere.